# Angular 9 Material Datepicker - Stop formatting user input

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm looking at this example from Angular Material on their DatePicker (MatDatepickerModule).
https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamjyjqqbxgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts

How do I change the behavior of the datepicker so that when are user types in a malformed date, the value doesn't get altered ? The current example datepicker will format `1/dd/2017` to `1/20/2017`. I don't want that. I want the value to remain unchanged but indicate on the form that the format is invalid. I tried using strict mode but that just empties the datepicker value.

```
providers: [
  {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {strict: true}}
]
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-datepicker-stop-formatting-user-input

Comment: @JuanPabloMorenoMartín, thanks for taking a look but editing your datepicker is behaving very strangely.